Locking only certains rows while copying data
I have 2 DBs, one is sender the other is target, they are both on different connexions.
I extract in a CSV datas from sender in order to copy them in target.
What I want to know is if there's a way to lock a certain number of rows while keeping the target table unlocked, I want to keep the table unlocked since it can receive new datas during the copying process thus will create duplicate PK problems.
From what I've seen using the setence FOR UPDATE can acheive that but I can't find the official doc for it.
\copy (SELECT * FROM $TABLE_TARGET FOR UPDATE) FROM '$TEMP_FILE' WITH CSV HEADER;

Is this statement correct or is there any other way to achieve this ?
PK info :

Sequence info :


No, that is not correct SQL. But you don't need any extra locks.

This is not correct SQL since it's in an .sh script but you get the idea of the SQL it achieves. Why wouldn't I need extra lock ? If I'm implementing data with a copy and at the same time a user implements a row both will conflicts no ?

How is your PK created? If  via  max+1 or similar then you cannot do this. You need to lock the table. If however you use a serial (i.e. default from a sequence) of a generated column then you do not need this. Postgres controls assignment of the key's value and you will not get duplicate PKs.

One of them will be locked automatically, and there is nothing you have to do.

Hey @Belayer sorry for the late answer, I'll update the post with the PK and sequence infos

I've just tested it with multiple millions of data and inserting into the table while copying, no issue detected so it seems to work well, thanks for your help
